# convert date in excel from dd-mm-yyyy to dd/mm/yyyy format and to check whether a date is valid or not

Tags: vba, excel

<strike>I'm having a hard time in converting the date from dd-mm-yyyy format to dd/mm/yyyy format.</strike>

For Example,
When i enter a date in excel as 25/02/2012 (dd/mm/yyyy), after entering the date if go in the next line it converts the date in the  25-02-2012 (dd-mm-yyyy) format.

what i want to do is that when i enter the date in (dd/mm/yyyy) format in excel it should keep it as it is and should not change it back to (dd-mm-yyyy) format when i go the next cell.

when i enter my date as the current system date my code gives me an error, i am having trouble validating the date i.e. is the date entered is a valid date or not

```
    Sub valid_date()
    ' ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    ' Final Code - Trial
    ' ---------------------------------------------------------------------

    Dim d1 As Variant
    Dim IssueDate As Variant
    Dim str As Variant

        d1 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(6, 1).value

            MsgBox " The Issue Date format is " & d1

        sysdate = Date

        MsgBox "System Date is " & sysdate


                If IsDateValid(d1) Then ' if date is in dd/mm/yyyy format then print this
            If (d1 > sysdate) Then
                MsgBox "Invalid date"
            End If
        End If
     End Sub

    Function IsDateValid(pdate) As Boolean

        IsDateValid = False

        Set RegExp = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")

        '   it only matches whether date is in dd/mm/yyyy format or not
        '
        '   [1-9]|0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-1]   ---> it allows the DATE  from 01 to 31
        '   [1-9]|0[1-9]|1[0-2]                 ---> it allows the MONTH from 01 to 12
        '   1[9][0-9][0-9]|2[0][0-9][0-9]       ---> it allows the YEAR  from 1900 to 2099
        '
        '   below is the regular expression for checking the date in dd/mm/yyyy format

        RegExp.Pattern = "^([1-9]|0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-1])[/]([1-9]|0[1-9]|1[0-2])[/](1[9][0-9][0-9]|2[0][0-9][0-9])$"

        ' check whether the date is in dd/mm/yyyy format or not....
        tempdate = RegExp.Test(pdate)

             If tempdate Then    ' if tempdate is in dd/mm/yyyy format than proceed further
                'If isdate(tempdate) Then  ' if date is a valid date then proceed further
                 If isdate(pdate) Then
                    IsDateValid = True
                Else
                    IsDateValid = False
                End If
            Else
                IsDateValid = False
            End If               
    End Function
```

i'm using the above mentioned code by using a regular expression to check whether the date is in dd/mm/yyyy format or not

<strike>but the problem which i'm facing is that it takes the date in excel as dd-mm-yyyy format whenever i enter the date in dd/mm/yyyy format.</strike>

i have updated my code a bit,
i also need one more help when i enter my date as the current system date it gives me error

for example,
when i enter my date as 09/09/2012 (suppose this your current system date) and when i check this date using IsDate method, it gives me an error

i have again edited my code,

Can anyone please help me on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I suggest you check the regional settings for dates on your computer. If you set it to use the "dd/mm/yyyy" format it will be used by Excel as well and hopefully remove the need for any RegEx VBA-code.

Second, if you do need to use VBA to reformat dates, I strongly suggest you use the Date data type instead of Variants. I also advise you to use Option Explicit at the top of your code and explicitly declare any variables in order to minimize typos and produce better quality code.

Third, I've looked through your code some more and it seems it will never work:

1. Because it is never declared, `tempdate` is a `Variant`

2. You assign `tempdate` to be a `boolean`, from the result of `RegExp.Test(pdate)`

3. So when you check `IsDate(tempdate)` it will always be `false`, since a `boolean` can never be a `Date`.

Again, if you use the `Date` data type, you can skip the RegEx... :)

Comment: i have updated my code very slightly, and instead of using    **`tempdate`** i'm now using **`pdate`** in the **`IsDate`** method as **`IsDate(pdate)`**, is this correct now ?

Comment: Yes, that should do it. I still recommend `Option Explicit` and `Date`, though. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need VBA/RegEx. Select the cells/columns where you input dates and create a Custom number format: `dd/mm/yyyy`. Now no matter how you type in a valid date (05-05-2000, 3-1-2010, 14/6-1990, etc.), it should be formatted as `dd/mm/yyyy`.

And, as Olle points out, you should use the `Date` object rather than `Variant` if you are going to be manipulating dates in VBA. This way you're working with the [serial number](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/datevalue-HP005209044.aspx) and not a string with potential formatting issues.

Answer (score 0):

I use Adobe online PDF to Excel and dates display correctly as MM/DD/YYYY but when extracting month (=Month()) it returns the DD portion. It is being interpreted as DD/MM/YYYY. I saved the file as a .csv closed and restarted excel and opened the .csv file and the dates were correct MM/DD/YYYY.